# Is there a way to add many times the same object to many to many fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm building an app where i have a model linked to another via a many to many relationship. Here is an example:
I have a sport training session, composed with multiple exercices, for example :

1. Sprint
2. Penalty
3. Penalty
4. Sprint

When i'm adding my exercices to my session, they are added in the front (angular) but when i refresh my page, only one copy of each exercice is kept in the session object.

Here are the models :

```
class Exercice(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Session(models.Model):
    sequences = models.ManyToManyField(Exercice, null=True, blank=True)
```

Any idea on how to have multiple times the same exercice in one Session ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the m2m will just contain the ids, not how many times you want them and the order.

It seems the issue is more related to your database structure.

Seems like you need a new table to store this information.

```
class Exercice(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Session(models.Model):
    exercices = models.ManyToManyField(Exercice, null=True, blank=True)

class Sequence(models.Model):
     exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     #any extra info there
     repetitions = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True) #how many time each?
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # used to generate the sequence of exercices
```

Then you can loop through this table to get what you want.

So in you backend when you create the session you should also create Sequence entry for each exercices you have within it

You can now access the sequence by looking at:

```
session = Session.objects.get(id=1#eg)
sequence = session.sequence_set.order_by('created_at')
```

Comment: And if i need to add in a precise order, is there a way to say that the first exercise is one sprint and 3rd exercise is also a sprint ?

Comment: You need to create a new ExerciceSession entry per exercice in your session.
And create them sequentialy, so when you retrieve them you sort them by `created_at` and you will have the session sequence right

Comment: After testing, it works perfectly as i was hoping ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a type of history table not mapping actually. You can add a middleware model such below.

```
    class ExerciseHistory(models.Model):
       exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```